# SQLDependency in ASP.NET with Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, sqldependency

I have used `SqlDependency` in `asp.net` to get notifications in application.  I want to use `SqlDependency` with sql stored procedure.  My stored procedure fetches records from more than 1 one table using join operation.

But, `SqlDependency`is not working here.

Can `SqlDependency` work with stored procedure or not?

If yes how I can use it..

Answer (score 0):

> Can SqlDependency work with stored procedure or not?

Yes.

When using Store procedure with SqlDependency

Do not use

- NOLOCK
- SET NOCOUNT ON